# automatic string recovery when out of range

Tags: c++

This is someone elses code !!! and it recovers automatically when it gets an out of range value for string....i want to know how that is possible ? without checking str.length() ! ok.

How do you recover automatically when out of range ? I am trying to understand someone elses code as thats what it does when start/n=134 and the str.length() is also 134(0-133).

```
FindEndOfToken(string &str, int start)
{
    UINT n = start;

    if( str[n] == '"' )
        doStuffOne();
    else
        doStuffTwo();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean exception handling? try {...} catch(...) {...} should work...
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

Comment: Are you saying that the program crashes and you are trying to recover from that?

Comment: it crashes when i write something like this which is what i expect.....but this is someone elses code and it doesnt crash or warn about out of range call....it just recovers and runs the else statement, i want to know how that is possible ?

Comment: Accessing outside the string is undefined behavior -- the fact in their code it happens not to crash and in your code it does is just coincidental.

Comment: i followed the code through xstring where it checks the exception but does something different compared to my test....is there some setting to ignore out of range errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out what was going on....seems to be this little bit of code...in a win32 app it sends the error to a file and relies on std::string to "recover"/ignore lol

```
// Turn on memory tracking
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF|_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF);
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT,_CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
_CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT,_CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR);
```

Comment: If this works, it will also make it much harder to find the bug, because it truly is a bug.

Comment: it works, dont know about bugs, but it does just simply fail gracefully when out of bounds which is kinda clever

Answer (score 3):

How about just comparing the argument to the string length?

```
if (start >= str.length())
    return;
```

---

If you're talking about exception, you have to catch the exception. However, this will not work if you are using the array indexing method, as that doesn't actually throw a proper exception, instead it results in undefined behavior which *might* lead to a crash.

Either use the check as above, *or* change to use the [`std::string::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) function to get the character and use [`try` and `catch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch) to catch the exception.

Comment: this is someone elses code im trying to understand, what u wrote is what i expected to be done....str[n] throws an exception but automatically recovers and runs the else statement

Comment: @KadeerSicario-Johnson Catch the exception, and do the other statement?

Comment: not my code, im trying to understand how the person who wrote it can make it automatically recover without checking the str.length etc

Comment: @KadeerSicario-Johnson You can't. Either change the code or expect weird behavior (including crashes).

Comment: @KadeerSicario-Johnson The only other solution is to add the checks in the function _calling_ `FindEndOfToken`.

Comment: is it possible to disable "string subscript out of range" errors ? so when the if statement fails it just runs the else statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing beyond the bounds of a `std::string` with `operator[]` is undefined behavior.  The fact that in their code it happens not to crash and in your code it crashes is just coincidental.

Comment: it doesnt crash, it gives u (normally) a pop up box warning about "string subscript out of range" and options to abort, ignore...in my case the error was being redirected to a file and str[toohighvalue] was returning a false enabling it to carry on regardless

Comment: @KadeerSicario-Johnson: perhaps it is being built with a string library that provides extra debugging checks.

Comment: nah it was just _CrtSetReport flags which were redirecting the error and allowing stdin::string to recover by itself